# total method and the sigil of a Bag variable in Perl 6

Tags: set, raku, bag

We can use the [`total`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/total) method to know the sum of all the weights in a `Bag`.

```perl6
> my $b = (1,2,1).Bag
Bag(1(2), 2)
> $b.total
3
```

But if we use the `%` sigil instead of `$` for our `Bag`, we get an error message.

```perl6
> my %b = (1,2,1).Bag
{1 => 2, 2 => 1}
> %b.total
No such method 'total' for invocant of type 'Hash'. Did you mean 'cotan'?
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

If `%b` is explicitly converted to `Bag` before `total`, it works:

```perl6
> %b.Bag.total
3
```

**The question:** I used to think that with `Set`, `Bag`, `SetHash` etc., using the `%` sigil is preferable. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Bind instead of assign

```
my %b := (1,2,1).Bag;
say %b.total
```

Binding (with `:=`) *[binds](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-Binding_operator)* the right hand side *directly* **to** the left hand side. In this case a value that does the [`Associative`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Associative) role gets bound *to* `%b`.

## Or assign to a `Bag`

Assigning (with `=`) *[assigns](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_=)* (copies) values *from* the right hand side **into** the *container* on the left hand side.

You can assign after first binding to a `Bag` as follows.

Immediately prior to an assignment a `my` declarator will bind a suitable container to the declared variable. By default it will be a `Hash` container if the variable has a `%` sigil.

But you can specify a variable `is` bound to some other type of container that's compatible with its sigil:

```
my %b is Bag = 1,2,1;
say %b.total
```

With this incantation you need to use `=` because, by the time that operator is encountered `%b` has already been bound to a `Bag` and now you need to assign (copy) **into** the `Bag`.

This way you get the simplicity of just providing a list of values (no explicit keys or `Bag` coercer/constructor necessary) because `=` is interpreted according to the needs of the container on its left, and a `Bag` choses to interpret the RHS of `=` as a list of keys whose occurrence count is what matters to it.

Comment: And if I have a `BagHash` and want to add new elements later, should I bind or assign? And how should I add new elements?

Comment: Not sure, gotta run, expect to be back in an hour or two.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky `my %b is BagHash = 1,2,1;` `%b{2} = 3;` `%b{1}++`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks, it works! But am I right that I can't use %b<2> instead of %b{2} here?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky `<a b c>` is short for `qw<a b c>` so `%h<a b c>` is short for `%h{qw<a b c>}`. Since you are dealing with an Int `2` and not a Str `"2"`, you cannot use `%h<2>`. (The default Hash uses Str keys, so in that case you could use `%h<2>`)

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks, I didn't understand that. So `%h{2}` has `2` as a key and `%h<2>` has `'2'`, right?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky That's correct. `<>` in that context is a quoting construct.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl 6, [assignment to a container can be coercive](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers#Assigning_and_binding_to_array_variables), that is, it coerces the value to that of the container. See this:

```
my $b = (1,2,1).Bag;
say $b.^name; # Bag

my %haШ = (1,2,1).Bag;
say  %haШ.^name; # Hash
```

Binding, on the other hand, [binds the type of the container to the contained thing](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers#Assigning_and_binding_to_array_variables).

So, the **answer**: you can still use the sigil, but as @raiph said above, use binding so that the Bag or BagHash is not coerced into a simple Hash.

```
my %real-haШ := (1,2,1).Bag;
say %real-haШ.^name; # Bag
```